# WPF How to customize Thumb and Repeatbutton of a RichTextBox VerticalScrollBar

Tags: wpf

I have a RichTextBox with a vertical scrollbar via `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`. Styling the Scrollbar itself works fine as I would expect it with the following inside `<RichTextBox.Resources>`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource steam2004ControlLight}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource steam2004BorderBright}"/>
</Style>
```

Trying to style the Thumb and Repeatbutton in a similar way however proved to be ineffective.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource steam2004ControlLight}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource steam2004BorderBright}"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource steam2004ControlLight}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource steam2004BorderBright}"/>
</Style>
```

Now, do note that I am only about two days into wrapping my head around WPF, so if my approach is totally busted, that's why :D
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Your approach does not work if a specific named Style is set to the control's `Style` property. You need to delve into what Style is actually applied to the `ScrollBar` of the `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Think you'll need to re template the scrollbar because it has a template will be setting the styles already. Here is the template for a scrollbar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollbar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Unless you merge matching named brushes as resources to override those used. That'll have side effects though.